# How to include Path in SharePoint Search API url

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, rest

I am developing functionality where I will be calling REST Search API's for SharePoint using React.

How can we pass `(path:https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Lists/Employee)` to `/sites/test/_api/search` API.

Not: I am not using **SPFx** here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `querytext`-parameter. It's described in [SharePoint Search REST API overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview)

E.g. `/sites/OneVSS/_api/search?querytext=(path%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fcontoso.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2Ftest%2FLists%2FEmployee)`

Also be sure to checkout the nice [SharePoint Search Query Tool](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/tree/master/Solutions/SharePoint.Search.QueryTool) - it helps to easily test access to the query-api.

Comment: thank you. I was trying query_parameter and didn't noticed querytext property